# Different groups of threads in a CUDA kernel

Tags: cuda

I'm trying to accelerate a crosscorrelation function in *C* using a *CUDA* kernel. For now this is what I have:

```
__global__ void xcorr(cuDoubleComplex *temp1, cuDoubleComplex *temp2, cuDoubleComplex *temp3, int Nb, int binM, int Nspb)
{
   for (int k1 = 0; k1 < Nb; k1++)
   {
       int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
       for (int j1 = 0; j1 < Nspb; j1++)
       {
           if ((j1 + idx) <(Nspb + binM))
           {
               temp3[idx + k1*(binM + 1)].x += (temp1[idx + j1 + (k1*(binM + Nspb))].x*temp2[j1 + (k1*Nspb)].x) + (temp1[idx + j1 + (k1*(binM + Nspb))].y*temp2[j1 + (k1*Nspb)].y);
               temp3[idx + k1*(binM + 1)].y += (-temp1[idx + j1 + (k1*(binM + Nspb))].x*temp2[j1 + (k1*Nspb)].y) + (temp1[idx + j1 + (k1*(binM + Nspb))].y*temp2[j1 + (k1*Nspb)].x);
           }
       }
    }
}
```

The result is what I expected but it still taking a while to operate, around `50 seconds`. When I summon the kernel I do it this way

`xcorr << <1, 1000 >> > (cuda_E2, cuda_A2, cuda_temp, Nb, *binM, Nspb);`

And what I was thinking is to send 6 blocks instead of just one, with 1000 threads each to avoid the loop with `j1` (`Nspb=5000`). I've tried in different ways but I can't find a way to use two different groups of threads, the first block the same way I'm using it and the other 5 to replace the `j1` loop. Could somebody show me how?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Consider doing your cross-correlation in the frequency domain, where it reduces to multiplication ?

Comment: Following @Paul comment, you may want to use cufft as cross correlation can be expressed very much like a convolution.

Comment: Thanks for the advise but I don't think it will work or at least that I don't thik it will be worthy, I'm not just doing one cross-correlation with both signals but I'm doing it with different extracts, so if I have to cut them, then do an fft to each extract to finally ifft to each one again...I think it will need more time

Comment: Hi @PaulR , I'm following your advise and it seems to be much faster but I have a problem with the result. I think it's because of the unnormalized fft that CUDA does, do you know when should I normalized the two signals?? After each fft? after the multiplication? after the inverse fft?

Comment: @IgnacioRey: since FFT/IFFT are linear operations you can just do one final `1/N` scaling operation at the end (after the final IFFT).

Comment: Ok @PaulR, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Write different code for the first block and the other blocks, put them into the branches of an if (blockIdx.x==0) and  start a <<<6,1000>>> grid?

```
__global__ void xcorr(...)
{
   if (blockIdx.x==0) {
       // do block zero stuff
   }
   else {
       // what the other blocks shall do
   }
}
```

In general, for 1D convulution/crosscorrelation:

1. put the Kernel in constant memory
2. let every thread block do the same, but for a different tile of the result array
3. let each block/tile load all elements of the input array which will be needed for this tile into shared memory (including the "halo" at the edges)

Comment: Mmmmm I'm trying what you're saying, applying conditionals but I can't use them properly, could you help me in my case?

Comment: But they both should work in the same lines and at the same time, I can't slip the code in that way.